# What order should we use to add a title and add spacing in dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard

I've created a plotly dash dashboard with 2 datatables next to each other horizontally (as opposed to stacked on top of one another).

I’m trying to add a header/title and spacing between data tables to my dash dashboard, but I can’t get things to look visually appealing.

I've tried:

- adding a html.H1 and html.title at the top of the main html.Div(children=[]). This just juxtaposes the text of the title in line with the data tables. Would this need its own html.Div()?
- adding some html.Br() after the html.H1 to try to create a space between the title text and tables.

Here is a reproduction of my code so far:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1('My Dashboard'),
        html.Br(), 
        html.Div([
            html.Label('Title1', style={'textAlign':'center','font-size': '30px'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id="filter_dropdown",
                options= columns1,
                multi=True,
                value=columns1,
            ),
            dash_table.DataTable(
                id="table-container",
                data=df.to_dict("records"),
                columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                style_table= {'overflowY':'auto', 'display':'in-line-block'},
                style_cell={'textAlign': 'center'},
                page_size=15,
            ),

        ]),  
       html.Div([
           html.Label('Title2', style={'textAlign':'center','font-size': '30px'}),
           dcc.Dropdown(
                id="filter_dropdown2",
                options=columns2,
                multi=True,
                value=columns2, 
            ),
            dash_table.DataTable(
                id="table-container2",          
                data=df2.to_dict("records"),
                columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df2.columns],
                style_table = {'overflowY':'auto', 'display':'in-line-block'},
                style_cell={'textAlign': 'center'},
                page_size=15,
            ),
        ]),
   
    ], 
    style = {"display": "flex"},
)
```

Current Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tZrH.png)
Desired Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pskoz.png)

I’m very new to dash and any help is appreciated  Thank you

Comment: Since you're using dash bootstrap components I'd recommend using its Row and Col components. Looking at your desired output image I see at least 2 rows. Put the 'My Dashboard' h1 in its own row and put the 2 divs below in a row together and each div in its own Col. Then you can remove style = {"display": "flex"} and the html.Br(). That should look more similar to your desired output.